# Codeigniter Login Validating Incorrect Username & Password

Tags: codeigniter

I am using php password_hash http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php to create my passwords. And to password_verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php to check passwords.

**Problem** When I try to verify my password it allows username and password that do not exist to login, but blocks username and passwords that are correct?

For some reason it is back to front? Not sure why?

**Question** How can I make sure it is not validating incorrect username and password using php password_verfiy

Model Functions

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $this->validate_password($password));
    $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function validate_password($password) {
    if (password_verify($password, $this->stored_hash())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function stored_hash() {
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username')); 
    $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row->password;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Controller Login**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->lang->load('common/login', 'english');
    $this->load->model('common/model_login');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}

public function index() {
    $data['title'] = $this->lang->line('heading_title');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|callback_validate_user');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $data['template'] = 'common/login_view';
        $this->load->view('common/template_view', $data);

    } else {

        redirect('common/dashboard');
    }
}

public function validate_user() {
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $result = $this->model_login->login($username, $password);

    if ($result) {

        $data = array(
            'is_logged' => true,
            'username' => $this->input->post('username')
        );  

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

    } else {

        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_user', $this->lang->line('error_login'));
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What kind of function is : password_verify ?

Comment: The one from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php as shown in my model

Comment: Ok, one more thing :) You query the db for a password based one Username, and after that you check the hash against the given password. If this is true, than why you query the db once more for check for an already checked username/password pair ? Try at the login function to return the value of the validate password :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with your `validate_password` function because this function return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. You need to return `$password` if your password match

```
public function validate_password($password) {
    if (password_verify($password, $this->stored_hash())) {
        return $password;// return password here
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Change your `login function` because you already match your password in validate_password() function

```
function login($username, $password) {

    if ($this->validate_password($password)) {
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting same error from my callback function.