# password_verify not worked with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**password_verify** - It gives false every time how can I resolve that issue.
Anyone have solution then please give me.
I have added the **password** file as manual still it gives the **Boolean** `false` as a return value.

```
private function verify_password_hash($password, $hash) {
  return password_verify($password, $hash);
}
```

Comment: add  your password_verify function code

Comment: which PHP Version do you use ?

Comment: @Yaseen - I'm assuming that OP is referring to PHP's built-in password_verify() function

Comment: Show the hash value that you're retrieving from the database

Comment: yes it's a password_verify function look https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/compatibility_functions.html#password_verify

Comment: i m using php 5  version and i m retriving this kind of hash value from database is $2y$10$Kim7Omo3r8k38WLJneXaEe1Rl0WOIen65zytcxW0OSZJRAJKe9mIe and i m encrypted using the PASSWORD_BCRYPT method and every time it return a bool false value

Comment: You're not trying to hash the value of `$password` (the user entered password) before passing it to `verify_password_hash()` are you? Or escaping or trimming it in any way?

Comment: @Mark Baker $this->db->select('password');
  $this->db->from('user');
  $this->db->where('email', $email);
  //$this->db->where('password', hash_password($password));
  $hash = $this->db->get()->row('password');
  //print_r($hash);exit;
  return $this->verify_password_hash($password, $hash);  i m using this function for login and private function verify_password_hash($password, $hash) {  
  return password_verify($password, $hash);
  
 }

Comment: WHat I'm saying is "where does `$password` come from".... is it exactly the value that the user has entered on the login form?

Comment: @Mark $password is came form the login post form like 1234567890 that i m enter from login page and that was goes in to that parameter

Comment: @Mark is there any solution for this

Comment: Unclear what's going wrong.... the password_hash() and password_verify() functions [work correctly](https://3v4l.org/uTfhi) so your hash and password don't match and that's what's being reported by password_verify()..... can you edit the question and show the exact code that you use for setting the password, and for the login validation

Comment: i can not able to click on edit the comment the edit icon can't be clickable and i debug the code then i retrive the length of password from database and length of password hash is equally same then its give the bool(false) as output of that function password_veriry and n my above comment i add the code for that also

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086271/codeigniter-login-validating-incorrect-username-password

Comment: The length of the password bears no relation to the length of the hash